# Records search function

Tags: scheme

I have a problem with my medical database in Scheme. I want to write a function that takes X symptoms and searches through my database for a match with a diagnose.

This is what I've done so far:

```
(define helper-match 
  (lambda (ls)
   (reverse
    (let loop ([ls ls] [found '()] [acc '()])
     (cond
      [(null? ls)
        acc]
      [(memq (car ls) found)
        (loop (cdr ls)
              found
              (if (memq (car ls) acc)
                  acc
                  (cons (car ls) acc)))]
      [else
        (loop (cdr ls)
              (cons (car ls) found)
              acc)])))))
```

Above is a function that check for duplicates but I don't know how to write it so it compares with my database.

the structure of the database looks like this:

```
(define *medical-db-2*
'((1
 (disease (meningit)
 (symptom (fever) (headache) (vertigo) (vomiting) (stiffness) (light sensitivity))))
(2
 (disease (encefalit)
 (symptom (fever) (headache) (vertigo) (vomiting) (disorientation) (cramps))))
```

Comment: And what's your database? we have no way to know, you should post all the relevant code

Comment: Edit your question and add an actual example of the database, with a couple of diagnoses, symptoms, etc. Use the real structure, not something "like this"

Comment: thanks edited the original post with code from the db